# tomcat connection pool issue

Tags: java, tomcat7, database-connection, connection-pooling

We are using tomcat connection pool for our application. From time to time it is observed from the log that connections are not available in the pool. Although it does not stop the application server itself, user action is interrupted due to this. We are adding following parameters to the data-source.:

```
<Resource
   name=XXXXX
   type=xxxxx
   username=xxxxx
   password=xxxxxx
   driverClassName=xxxxx
   maxIdle=2
   url=xxxxx
   maxActive=10
/>
```

Question: Is it possible that connection pool becomes empty for certain duration and then connections are again avaible?

Comment: I would have thought you would want minIdle

Comment: The answer to the question you asked is "YES", but that answer is probably worthless as you already know it from your program's behavior.

Comment: @Scary minIdle is defaulted to initialSize which is 10

Comment: @ravthiru I would assume that it would change the default if the maxIdle size is less than initialSize.

Answer (score 0):

The connection pool won't drop to 0 unless all idle connections fail validation queries. What's happening here is that your connections are idle timing out down to the maxIdle size of 2. Idle connections are typically a good thing to have because they avoid the exact problem you're coming across; that it is expensive to open new connections.

Comment: Hello john, thanks for your reply. Will it help if I add initialSize and minIdle parameters.

Comment: When the connection pool boots it will create initialSize connections. As more connections are simultaneously requested it will grow to maxActive. Once those connections become idle it will drop to maxIdle. Once those idle connections timeout it will drop to minIdle. Raising both maxIdle and minIdle will result in keeping more idle connections for longer. Raising initialSize will push idle connection creation to boot instead of on user demand. Setting minIdle to initialSize is a pretty good point to start at as well.